# Dummy Switches - Charge Injection and Capacitive Feedthrough

Tags: cmos

[image]

[R. Jacob Baker]

I have some confusion regarding a technique using dummy switches to compensate for charge injection and capacitive feedthrough.

1. How does M2 compensate for the charge injection of M1? When M1 turns off and 1/2 the channel charge flows to M2, how do they "cancel" if they are both NMOS devices?
2. How does the Cload capacitor ever get charged in the first place? M1 is being driven be one clock source and M2 is being driven by the inverted version of that. Then there's never a time when the two are both on together to provide a path to Cload? I understnad that the author said that the signal "should also be slightly delayed" but wouldn't cause more charge injection due to M2 now?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Why is it an opposite sign? It's still an NMOS. When M2 turns on, a channel is formed and free electrons are available for conduction. At the same time, M1 turns off and it's 1/2 channel electrons now come to M2. How are they going to cancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Because the charge injection on M2 is the opposite sign from that on M1. "Notice that the clock signal (on M2) is the complement of (...) M1".

The charge injection is basically capacitive coupling from the large amplitude voltage step on the gate, to the channel (divides between source and drain ends).

By driving M2 with the opposite polarity voltage step, you can cancel most (almost all, with care) of it out.

2) Because when M2 is off, it is still shorted out, and the short conducts.

I wish I had seen this trick earlier ... I could have used it in 1983 or so...

Comment: Oh damn. Completely missed that short even though it was highlighted.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much.